# A build system with CMAKE or not for system composition

Tags: cmake, composition, build-system

To be specific, the question can be asked as: Can you replace a Linux kernel build system with a build system that is mainly based on CMAKE?

I know CMAKE is good for building a cross-platform package, like a library or an application. But I suspect it is not good for a system consisting of a few components and you want to advance the development of each components separately. In another words, CMAKE probably is not good for a build system that is focusing on composition of a system from different components.

To create a build system for system composition, it may be better to use the git-repo tool to manage the top-level composition. At the top-level, it is more about pulling packages at different hashes into a system layout. After that, the further building steps can use CMAKE or any other build techniques. As an example, [Legato](http://legato.io) comes to mind.

To build system experts, what is your opinion?

Comment: `To build system experts, what is your opinion?` - Clear sign for *primary opinion-based* questions, which are not suited for Stack Overflow format.

Comment: In my experience, I have wrapped kernel build system into CMake for build Linux kernel modules. So nothing is impossible.

Comment: Programming itself is more an art than a science. Yes, it is an opinion based question. If you think you are an expert, I'd like to hear your opinion on this. Thanks for stating your experience of wrapping kernel modules with CMake. I'm to some extent convinced to give up some of my original opinion.

Comment: Tsyvarev, If you provide your views as to why you would do it than not, it must be a great answer to my original question. That surely will benefit our readers than just closing this question.

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow is neither a forum nor a chat, so it *isn't suited* for such "discussion" questions. See [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). I have pointed to my experience only for show, that there are different points of view on your problem (using CMake for build Linux kernel), so the question is actually *opinion-based*.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for sharing your views, though in a limited way. Yes there are different views on my question, as I asked why and why not in the title.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. In particular, "Can you replace a Linux kernel build system with a build system that is mainly based on CMAKE?" immediately shows that "there is no actual problem to be solved".

Comment: Thanks ivan_pozeev. I followed your link through to the section below where you pointed to: Constructive subjective questions. I really think someone from the experts team should share their opinions on the question I'm asking. Practically we as average developers spent huge amount of time trying to cope with inadequate build tools in many situations that is out of most developer's control. Any improvement in the area should benefit us a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the list of related questions the question "[which suits linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060632/which-suits-linux-gnu-make-vs-cmake-vs-codeblocks-vs-qmake?rq=1)" links to [two interesting other options - scons and waf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4060653/9489082).

Both [scons and waf](https://github.com/SCons/scons/wiki/SconsVsOtherBuildTools), are a good candidate to be a buildsystem tool: They have the full capability that a fully-fledged programming language owns. That makes them well suited to write a buildsystem that can compose the system anyway that you can write a program to represent. And they by themselves are a build system, no requirement for a separate build system. Compare: autotools, cmake, qmake all generates makefiles and requires a separate make system to do the build.

Back to the original poster's question: If the project team is good on Python, then use scons or waf but not cmake. If your team members are really good at cmake handling but not python, why not cmake.

Comment: after looked around, scons and waf look good though may not be ideal. voted for reopen so other answers can come in.